# Side-by-Side plotting in bsdoc using ReporterS

Tags: r, plot, reporters

I wish to plot the following plots next to each other in a HTML doc;

```
mydoc = addPlot(doc = mydoc,fun = function() barplot(as.matrix(Sustainability_Scores),col="green",ylab = "Sustainability Score",main = 'Sustainability Scores',las = 2))

mydoc = addPlot(doc = mydoc,fun = function() pie(as.matrix(Sustainability_Scores_pie),labels = c("Health","Basic Needs","Knowledge","Energy","Waste Water & Pollution","Technology","Total"), main = "Sustainability Score Distribution"))
```

How do I go about doing this? When i currently plot them, they appear one above the other, which is not really what i'm looking for.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the suggestion of this useR:

https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs/issues/102